# How to find adjacent values in a column based on another column value in Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table like below

[image]

From the above table I Need to select adjacent values from val3 column based on Number column

I Need output like below :

[image]

Comment: @OcasoProtal Sorry 6024:11,12 too.... Edited the question

Comment: Why not only 1 row with 6015,1,2,9

Comment: @BernhardHofmann - I am trying to get the output with cursor

Comment: I don't follow your desired results. It just looks like the original table missing two rows.

Comment: @MartinSmith Lets take the values Number: 6012 , Val3 : 1  the value 1 is not adjacent to 10 or 11 with respect to Number value 6012, So we have eliminated value from the output and fallows for the other values too..

Comment: Oh I see. Are the values of `Val1` and `Val2` columns significant? In your example data they are the same within a given Number. Is this always the case? If not does that affect the result?

Comment: @MartinSmith - Yes the values of Val1 & Val2 data is same with respect to Number Value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH T1
     AS (SELECT *,
                DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [Number] ORDER BY [Val3]) - [Val3] AS Grp
         FROM   YourTable),
     T2
     AS (SELECT *,
                COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [Number], Grp) AS Cnt
         FROM   T1)
SELECT [Number],
       [Val1],
       [Val2],
       [Val3]
FROM   T2
WHERE  Cnt > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

An ugly solution would be:

```
select d.number, d.val1, d.val2, d.val3  from table d
 where exists
 (select * from table t
         where t.number = d.number
           --and t.val1 = d.val1 
           --and t.val2 = d.val2
           and (t.val3 = d.val3 - 1 or t.val3 = d.val3 + 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can identify a sequential set of numbers by the fact that the number - its position in the set will be constant, e.g.

```
Val3 | RowNumber | Val - RowNumber
 4   |  1        |   3
 5   |  2        |   3
 6   |  3        |   3
 8   |  4        |   4
 9   |  5        |   4
```

As you can see the `Val - RowNumber` column remains constant for each sequential set. So to apply this to your query:

```
WITH GroupedT AS
(   SELECT  Number,
            Val1,
            Val2,
            Val3,
            GroupingSet = Val3 - DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Number, Val1, Val2 ORDER BY Val3)
    FROM    T
), SequentialT AS
(   SELECT  Number,
            Val1,
            Val2,
            Val3,
            SequenceCount = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Number, Val1, Val2, GroupingSet)
    FROM    GroupedT
)
SELECT  Number, Val1, Val2, val3
FROM    SequentialT
WHERE   SequenceCount > 1
ORDER BY Number, Val1, Val2, Val3;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/08f66/3)**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you're trying to do is eliminate any records that contain a Val3 value that doesn't have any adjacent Val3 values in other records.  To do that, I think you can use something like this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM myTable t1
JOIN myTable t2 ON t1.Number = t2.Number 
AND t1.Val1 = t2.Val1 
AND t1.Val2 = t2.Val2 
AND (t2.Val3 IN (t1.Val3 - 1, t1.Val3 + 1))
```

Comment: You need to add `DISTINCT` otherwise you'll get  6020:5 twice!